How to disable JavaScript warnings in a .NET C# project in Visual Studio?
I have a .NET 7 Web MVC project.  Visual Studio 2022 shows me JavaScript warnings, mostly from various libraries that live under wwwroot/lib.  There is little I can do about these warnings since I don't want to mess with existing libraries.
How can I get rid of them (other than manually adding specific numbered NOWARN entries to the csproj)?


This should be possible in the .editorconfig, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78647520/2181514  Move "library"/ 3rd-party js files to their own folder and add an .editorconfig there.

You can try: go to Tools > Options… and search for ESLint:
Uncheck the checkbox in front of Enable ESLint, restart Visual Studio, and you are done.
If the errors persist, you can open Tools > Options… again, search for JavaScript Errors and disable the setting:
Restart again, and now Visual Studio will no longer show you any JavaScript errors.
